# How To Set Background Color To Text In React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, view

I am new to react native so please help me to figure this out.
I want to set background color to the text but this is some kind of different design.

[image]

I have tried with this code:-

```
<View style={styles.titleWrapper}>
     <View style={styles.titleInner}></View>
     <Text style={styles.title}>Mobile Verification</Text>
</View>

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
   titleWrapper: {
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        marginTop: '8%',
        flexDirection: 'row'
    },
    titleInner: {
        backgroundColor: COLORS.LIME_GREEN,
        width: '50%',
        height: 22,
        position: 'absolute',
        bottom: 0,
        left: '23%',
        borderRadius: 14,
        opacity: 0.5,
    },
   title: {
        color: COLORS.BLACK,
        fontWeight: 'bold',
        fontSize: 25,
        textAlign: 'center',
    },
})
```

I want to implement same thing for other screens as well.
Here the width of background color will be differ by text to text. So if length of text is short then we need width according to the text.

Please guide me how to apply the styles in it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried set ```backgroundCokor``` on ```Text``` element itself?

Comment: Yes, I tried but it is not working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

you add zIndex

```
    titleInner: {
        backgroundColor: COLORS.LIME_GREEN,
        width: '50%',
        height: 22,
        position: 'absolute',
        bottom: 0,
        left: '23%',
        borderRadius: 14,
        opacity: 0.5,
        zIndex: 1,
    },
   title: {
        color: COLORS.BLACK,
        fontWeight: 'bold',
        fontSize: 25,
        textAlign: 'center',
        zIndex: 2,
    },
```

and check again.

[Demo](https://snack.expo.dev/@zhenguet/color-demo)

Comment: Have you tried by adding smaller length text because I tried in that demo for smaller text. I want to adjust background color as per the text length.

Comment: if you want to do that, I think you should get the width and height in nativeEvent of view and make style follow it.